# UseCookieAuthentication with Distributed Cache Ticket Store removing cache entries before set timetout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, caching, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core application where I am configuring cookie authentication and OpenID Connect authentication.  I am also using Session and a distributed SQL server cache.

In the cookie authentication configuration, I am setting the SessionStore property to use my distributed cache ticket store.  I have my session timeout set to 60 minutes.  When I put items into session directly, it uses the sql cache and the entries show a 60 minute sliding expire time.  That all works fine.  Now, when the cookie auth uses the distributed cache ticket store, i can see the entries in the database as well (with a sliding 60 minute timeout).  But if I let a web page sit for 20 minutes or more and then refresh the page, the ticket store removes the cache entry in the database for the cookie; even though the full 60 minutes have not passed.  When debugging the ticket store, i see the call to Retrieve get called, then a call to Remove, and then another call to Retrieve; which at that point there is no more cache entry.

I'm sure I'm missing some setting somewhere, but the just the cookie cache entries are being cleaned up and removed prematurely.  I cannot figure out why.

Here are the relevant parts of my startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // app insights
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(this.Configuration);

        // authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(options => options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // options
        services.AddOptions()
            .Configure<ConfigurationOptions>(this.Configuration)
            .AddUtilitiesLayerConfigurationOptions(this.Configuration)
            .AddDataLayerConfigurationOptions(this.Configuration)
            .AddServicesLayerConfigurationOptions(this.Configuration)
            .AddWebAppLayerConfigurationOptions(this.Configuration);

        // caching/session
        services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(this.ConfigureSqlServerCacheOptions);
        services.AddSession(this.ConfigureSessionOptions);

        // mvc
        services.AddMvc(ConfigureMvcOptions);

        // custom services
        services
            .AddConfigurationLayerServices()
            .AddCommonLayerServices()
            .AddUtilitiesLayerServices()
            .AddServicesLayerServices(this.Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ITicketStore distributedCacheTicketStore)
    {
        // setup logging
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        // app insights request telemetry (this must be first)
        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        // exceptions
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions { SourceCodeLineCount = 10 });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
        }

        // app insights exception telemetry (right after exception config)
        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        // session
        app.UseSession();

        // status code pages (redirect to error controller)
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");

        // static files
        // this is before auth, so no static files require auth
        // if we wanth auth for static files, move this after the auth middleware
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // auth
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(this.BuildCookieAuthenticationOptions(distributedCacheTicketStore));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(this.BuildOpenIdConnectOptions());

        // mvc
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    private CookieAuthenticationOptions BuildCookieAuthenticationOptions(ITicketStore ticketStore)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationOptions();
        this.Configuration.Bind(configuration);

        return new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
            CookieName = configuration.Session.AuthenticationCookieName,
            AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied",
            SessionStore = ticketStore
        };
    }

    private OpenIdConnectOptions BuildOpenIdConnectOptions()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationOptions();
        this.Configuration.Bind(configuration);

        return new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            ClientId = configuration.AzureActiveDirectory.ClientID,
            Authority = configuration.AzureActiveDirectory.Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = configuration.AzureActiveDirectory.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = this.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                OnRemoteFailure = this.OnRemoteFailure,
                OnTokenValidated = this.OnTokenValidated,
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = this.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                OnAuthenticationFailed = this.OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is my DistributedCacheTicketStore:

```
public class DistributedCacheTicketStore : ITicketStore
{
    private readonly DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions options;
    private readonly IDistributedCache distributedCache;
    private readonly IDataProtector dataProtector;
    private readonly ILogger<DistributedCacheTicketStore> logger;

    public DistributedCacheTicketStore(
        IOptions<DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IDistributedCache distributedCache,
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        ILogger<DistributedCacheTicketStore> logger)
    {
        this.options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        this.distributedCache = distributedCache;
        this.dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(this.GetType().FullName);
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var ticketBytes = this.dataProtector.Protect(TicketSerializer.Default.Serialize(ticket));
        await this.distributedCache.SetAsync(key, ticketBytes, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions { SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(this.options.Session.TimeoutMinutes) });
        this.logger.AuthenticationTicketStoredInCache(key);
        return key;
    }

    public async Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var ticketBytes = this.dataProtector.Protect(TicketSerializer.Default.Serialize(ticket));
        await this.distributedCache.SetAsync(key, ticketBytes, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions { SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(this.options.Session.TimeoutMinutes) });
        this.logger.AuthenticationTicketRenewedInCache(key);
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
    {
        var ticketBytes = await this.distributedCache.GetAsync(key);
        var ticket = TicketSerializer.Default.Deserialize(this.dataProtector.Unprotect(ticketBytes));
        this.logger.AuthenticationTicketRetrievedFromCache(key);
        return ticket;
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        var ticketBytes = await this.distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key);
        if (ticketBytes != null)
        {
            await this.distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);
            this.logger.AuthenticationTicketRemovedFromCache(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably way too late but in case anyone runs across similar here was my question and the answer I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908610/cookie-authentication-early-expiration/49961076#49961076

Comment: I think those `IDataProtector` are superfluos and not needed. The cookie isn't going to the client anyway.